# Unity3D stackoverflow error appears when comparing two strings

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine, stack-overflow

So im making a game and im currently working on the inventory system and i created an Item and an Inventory class, and i compare some properties of items in the inventory class, i get a stackoverflow error when i try to access the ID string in the item class, here is the inventory and item class:

```
public class item
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public int amount;
    public int stacksize;
}

public class inventory
{
    public bool open = false;
    item[] items = new item[43];
    //first 30 inv
    //next 5 hotbar
    //next 4 armor
    //next 4 equipment
    public GameObject invScreen;

    public void printInv()
    {
        foreach (item n in items)
        {
            PlayerController.print(n.id + "   |   " + n.amount);
        }
    }

    public void addItem(item add)
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach(item x in items)
        {
            item f = x;
            if (f.id == add.id)
            {
                if (add.amount + f.amount <= f.stacksize)
                {
                    items[i].amount += add.amount;
                    f.amount = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    f.amount = (add.amount + f.amount) - f.stacksize;
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
        i = 0;
        foreach(item x in items)
        {
            item f = x;
            if (f.id == "filler")
            {   
                if (add.amount + f.amount <= f.stacksize)
                {
                    items[i].amount += add.amount;
                    f.amount = 0;
                }
                else
                { 
                    f.amount = (add.amount + f.amount) - f.stacksize;
                    addItem(f);
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
    }

    public void swap(int item1, int item2)
    {
        item x = items[item1];
        item y = items[item2];
        items[item1] = y;
        items[item2] = x;
    }

    public void init()
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach(item v in items)
        {
            item e = new item();
            e.stacksize = 1;
            e.amount = 1;
            e.id = "filler";
            items[i] = e;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

I know my code is probably not optimized nor organized so sorry about that.......

I tried searching for code that might cause an infinite loop but i haven't found anything, so thats why im here....

Comment: "i get a stackoverflow error when i try to access the ID string in the item class" What makes you think it is when you access the id? Looking at the code ```addItem``` has a call to ```addItem``` within itself, this would be where you are getting a stackoverflow. Add some debug prints before calling the inner addItem so you can determine why it keeps calling itself.

Comment: I forgot to say that when i click on the error i puts me to that line, i tought that it puts me there because the error is there
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

OK i solved it thank you, no more answears needed :D

Comment: Please Edit the Answer, providing the solution u used and mark it as accepted